# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'min'

Tags: python

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.util import random_noise

I = cv2.imread('roses.jpg', 0)
gauss = random_noise(I, mode='gaussian', seed=None, clip=True )


plt.subplot(241), plt.imshow(img), plt.title('origin')
plt.subplot(242), plt.imshow(gauss), plt.title('gaussian')


plt.show();
```

## Detect if a signed image was input. how to fix this problem

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/skimage/util/noise.py in random_noise(image, mode, seed, clip, **kwargs)

```
if image.min() < 0:
              low_clip = -1.
         else:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.util import random_noise

img = cv2.imread('roses.jpg', 0)
gauss = random_noise(img, mode='gaussian', seed=None, clip=True )


plt.subplot(241), plt.imshow(img), plt.title('origin')
plt.subplot(242), plt.imshow(gauss), plt.title('gaussian')


plt.show();

if img.min() < 0:
    low_clip = -1.
else:
```

You are saving the image as `I`, then using it as `img`, then trying to find the min of `image`. Your namespace is probably very cluttered and references to old things are hanging around. Be consistent and it should work if the img has a min method/attribute. If it does not, then you need to find the array that the img class represents. I suspect that opencv works like an array so the following should work:

```
import numpy as np
if np.min(img) < 0:
    low_clip = -1.
else:
    #Do something else
```